# How to use Nodejs mongoose findOne with String condition?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to do this but it seems that im doing wrong, Thank for your help.

```
var cond = '{ location :'+ value +'}'; places.findOne(cond, function ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//updated due to comment below

var query_obj = {}
query_obj[var1] = var2

mySchema.findOne(query_obj).exec(function(err,data){
  console.log("this will be your query results: ", data )
})
```

Comment: sorry i didnt mention that even location is a variable, i want to use it with dynamic keys. expl: mySchema.findOne({ varkey : varvalue})

Comment: updated.  You can just pass the findOne function an object variable.